# After validation a field, property has last valid value

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

In my WPF project i started use ValidationRule with text fields and found a problem. I created simple project to test ValidationRule. Everything works fine, but if my input value is not in valid range, my property store **last valid** value. Thats why i have a question: how can I check current value, that not valid for **ValidationRule**? May be, i doing something wrong?

Main Window

```
</Window ... >
  <Window.Resources>
        <ControlTemplate x:Key="errorTemplate">
            <Border BorderBrush="OrangeRed" BorderThickness="2">
                <Grid>
                    <AdornedElementPlaceholder/>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding [0].ErrorContent}" Foreground="OrangeRed"
                               VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                               Margin="0,0,4,0"/>
                </Grid>
            </Border>
        </ControlTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>

    <StackPanel>
        <TextBox Validation.ErrorTemplate ="{StaticResource errorTemplate}"
                 HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center"
                 Width="200" Margin="0 20">          
                <TextBox.Text>
                <Binding Path="ForText" 
                         UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
                        <Binding.ValidationRules>
                            <local:EmptyFieldRule/>
                        </Binding.ValidationRules>
                    </Binding>
                </TextBox.Text>           
        </TextBox>
        <Button Content="Check"
                Command="{Binding ForCommand}"
                 HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                 VerticalAlignment="Center"
                Width="40"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

View model for Window, that i set in DataContext:

```
public class MainWindowVM : VM
    {
        private string _text = "some text";
        public string ForText
        {
            get => _text;
            set { _text = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ForText)); }
        }
        public ICommand ForCommand { get; set; }
        public MainWindowVM() { ForCommand = new RelayCommand(() => MessageBox.Show(ForText)); }
    }
```

Validation rule:

```
public class EmptyFieldRule : ValidationRule
    {
        public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
        {
            string information = value as string;
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(information))
                return new ValidationResult(false, "!!!");

            return ValidationResult.ValidResult;
        }
    }
```

Comment: It is unclear what you are asking! Please explain this "how can I check current value, that not valid for ValidationRule?". You have added EmptyFieldRule, so if field is not valid it must have empty or white-space string.

Comment: Yes, you right. Value should be empty. For example: i insert in texbox "5", press button and get MessageBox with '5'. But, when i remove '5', textbox becoms empty, ValidationRule shows me the error template, i press button and MessageBox still has '5'. And i don't understand, why does property in viewmodel still contein '5'

Comment: Did you expect a validationrule to allow the user to input invalid data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Binding` in wpf evaluate all the `ValidationRule` before updating the value. You have to make few changes in the `EmptyFieldRule` class to achieve this. This is a kind of trick to resolve your issue but there are other better ways to implement the same.

Change `ValidationStep` property to `ValidationStep.UpdatedValue` and use `Reflection` to get updated value in the `ValidationResult` method.

```
public class EmptyFieldRule : ValidationRule
{
    public EmptyFieldRule()
    {
        this.ValidationStep = ValidationStep.UpdatedValue;
    }
    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        var expression = value as BindingExpression;
        var information = expression?.DataItem?.GetType()?.GetProperty(expression.ResolvedSourcePropertyName)?.GetValue(expression.DataItem) as string;
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(information))
            return new ValidationResult(false, "!!!");

        return ValidationResult.ValidResult;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes, I thought about something like that, but didn't know how to describe correctly. This method helps me. Thanks a lot!